# order column from union select by another column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, union

I have a table:

**Message**

```
id, user_from_id, user_to_id, send_date, message, is_readed
```

and I would like to select all the users that I chat with, so my query looks like this:

```
SELECT user_from_id as user_id
FROM message
WHERE user_to_id=xxx
UNION
SELECT user_to_id
FROM message
WHERE user_from_id=xxx
```

..and I have a list of user_id's, the problem is that I can't find a way to order those id's by send_data, so that at the beginning of that list i would have a user that i lately chat with

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about dispensing with the `union`?

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN m.user_to_id = xxx THEN m.user_from_id
             ELSE m.user_to_id
        END) as user_id
FROM message m
WHERE xxx IN (m.user_to_id, m.user_from_id)
ORDER BY m.send_date DESC;
```

This is probably not what you really want, because users will appear multiple times in the list.  What you really want is:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN m.user_to_id = xxx THEN m.user_from_id
             ELSE m.user_to_id
        END) as user_id
FROM message m
WHERE xxx IN (m.user_to_id, m.user_from_id)
GROUP BY m.user_id
ORDER BY MAX(m.send_date) DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with x as(
SELECT user_from_id as user_id, send_date
FROM message
WHERE user_to_id=xxx
UNION
SELECT user_to_id, send_date
FROM message
WHERE user_from_id=xxx
) select user_id 
from x 
order by send_date
```

This wraps the `UNION` query up with the `send_date` column into a single variable, from which you can then `SELECT` and `ORDER BY send_date`.